# After appending <br> to the parent's innerHTML, the child's innerHTML can't be changed anymore

Tags: javascript, html

I have a parent and I add a child to it. After that I append `<br>` to the parent's `innerHTML`, but after that the child's `innerHTML` can't be changed anymore. What's going on here? Why isn't the final result "bbb"?

But if you comment out `container.innerHTML += "<br>"`, it does change to "bbb".

```js
let container = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(container)

let child = document.createElement('div')
child.innerHTML = "aaa"
container.appendChild(child)

container.innerHTML += "<br>"
child.innerHTML = "bbb"
```

Comment: Replacing `innerHTML` (which is what `+=` does) removes any previously present element references. I suggest if you want to append elements, then use `.append()` or similar DOM methods

Comment: @Phil But `console.log(child)` after the <br> line doesn't give an error, in fact it logs `<div>bbb</div>` - the changed html - even though it doesn't change on the page. That's what's confusing!

Comment: The `child` element reference still exists (in memory), it just no longer refers to an element in the document. IMO, `innerHTML` is a _hack_ that should be avoided whenever possible